# why does the method print 10 instead of 12

Tags: java

how is possible when i have the rolling code.
There is a method there that prints 10, when i expect it to print 12:

```
public class Opgave1d {

    PrintStream out;
    int p = 5;
    int q = 10;

    public Opgave1d() {
        out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    }

    void methode1(int p) {
        this.p = p + 2;
        q = 4 * p;
        out.printf("%d\n%d\n", p, q);
    }

    void start(){
        methode1(q);
    }
}
```

How is it possible that it prints 10 and 40, the 40 i get it, but why does it not print :
12
40????
I appreciate any help!

Comment: Since you used 'this.p' in your code, you probably knew this if you had investigated it properly.

Comment: This is homework, have you tried a few things?

Comment: Do you even know why you put `this` ?! Anyways, read [Shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing)

Comment: This is an exam, thank you all for the effort to explain!

Comment: This is not for you to judge:)), I'm sure you didn't start from knowing everything. Thanks to all who want to explain and to the people like you who don't, pls do not bother to read or comment if it annoys you. Will be favour for both!

Comment: @user3710255 There have been a lot of people asking terrible zero effort questions on Stackoverflow recently so you are seeing some of the backlash against that. Your question was about a simple error, but the question itself was presented clearly so I (and many others) were happy to answer.

Comment: and this one indeed is a zero effort one, you just google `this java` (http://alturl.com/986f6) and you'll get the answer. and what was included in my comment is even the exact answer you're searching for.

Comment: For beginners unfortunately isn't so obvious, and google sometimes need time to sort which info is correct and which isn't. Here i got the answer for seconds. Is it not that the purpose of this site? Place where ppl like me can ask silly questions..even tho simple for you, not as obvious for me.

Comment: Any way I am really grateful that such site exists, it has answered all of my questions much better and much faster then any of the student assistants who never really have time to talk or explain. I gotten further with my materials tnx to the ppl here who want to answer. Tnx!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is printing `p` (the local variable) not `this.p` (the member variable).

Comment: @user3710255 You should accept one of the answers (click on the little tick by the answer) :)

Answer (score 5):

You're shadowing your variables.

```
this.p
```

refers to the instance's `p` variable, while `p` refers to the local parameter variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually shadowing the property with the formal argument in the `out.printf`. Try printing out `this.p`.

I suggest that you use different name conventions (prefixes on properties could help) between properties and formal arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change the value of `p`; you changed the value of `this.p`. *These are not the same variable!*

`p` is a local variable within `methode1`, whereas `this.p` is an instance variable (a member of the class). If you want to refer to `this.p`, you must do so explicitly, like you did two lines above when you assigned `this.p = p+2`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it prints the local variable p

```
out.printf("%d\n%d\n", p, q);
```

not the member

```
out.printf("%d\n%d\n", this.p, q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printing the value of "p" which is the parameter, q, and isn't changed. If you had printed self.p, instead of just p,it would have given you 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
   void start(){
        methode1(12);
    }
```

then

```
 void methode1(int 10) {
        this.p = 10 + 2;
        q = 4 * 10;
        out.printf("%d\n%d\n", 10, 40);
    }
```

Son to print `12` and `40`. You should refer to field p in your class like this

```
 void methode1(int 10) {
        this.p = p + 2;
        q = 4 * p;
        out.printf("%d\n%d\n", this.p, q);
    }
```

When you use key word `this` you refer to instance members.

or avoid conflicted names with fields and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you must print this.p to see desired output.Here the method variable is in local scope so you are getting p value as 10